# Path to ContentArea in Exact Target?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a beginner's question -  I'm trying to follow the tutorial called "How to include an RSS feed in an email message," which is located [here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/how_to_include_an_rss_feed_in_an_email_message_using_ampscript/).

I've followed the tutorial by creating a template with an HTML-only content area (I've named that content area "**RSSParse**," just the same as in the tutorial)  And I've inserted the url for my rss feed into that content area, as instructed.

I've also named the template "**RSSParse**" and it is located inside the "**My Templates**" folder.

However, when I attempt to target the content area named "RSSParse" using the following code:

```
Set @xml = ContentAreaByName("path/to/Content/area")
```

(or/any/other/path), I repeatedly get the same error:

**"A scripting error has occurred.
Content Area "my templates\RSSParse\RSSParse\" could not be found.
Client ID: 6222160"**

Of course,  this means that the path to my content area titled "RSSParse" is incorrect.  But, I don't know the file structure of this system and, therefore, I am having a great deal of trouble figuring out what the correct path would be.

What is the correct path to the content area named "RSSParse"?

Content area name: RSSParse
Template name: RSSParse
Located inside this folder: My Templates

(Sneaking in a bonus question: Is there anyplace I can go to see the entire file structure of the system I'm working with? It would be useful for future reference, as I'm sure I'll have many more questions that are similar to this one. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you may need to use the backslash, and not the forward slash.  I doubt that is your issue.

You need to have a folder named RSSParse for 'my contents\RSSParse\RSSParse' to find it.  In your current setup, if RSSParse is in 'my contents', then 'my contents\RSSParse' should work.

Unfortunately, "No" is the answer to your bonus question.

Good luck!

Comment: Is it necessary for the template with the named content area to be stored inside of "My Contents" before it can be targeted with ContentAreaByName()?   Currently, the template with the named content area is stored inside of the folder called "My Templates"   Using the path "my templates/RSSParse" does not work.

Comment: Oh, okay! I just hovered over the content block titled "Save to Content Library" and saved that content block to the folder "My Contents."  It is important for the content block to be inside of the folder "My Contents." 

In order to target a content area, then that content area does have to be inside the folder "My Contents"